# What happens when I select "new station from song" in iTunes 12.2?

Tags: itunes, apple-music, itunes-radio

When I click "new station from song" in iTunes 12.2 the currently playing song stops playing and as far as I can tell nothing else happens. Does a station get created somewhere? I can't find any radio stations except for the official Apple ones in the tab "Radio". I am subscribed to Apple Music and signed into my iTunes account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is a bug in iTunes, happens to me as well as others. There's a few posts on the apple support forum:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7106282
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7115175
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7112080

There's more if you search there, but no solutions available.

## UPDATE:

Bug is fixed for me in iTunes 12.2.2.25